# Removing black frames with constant framerate

Tags: ffmpeg

i'm trying to create a video made of jpgs (camera-snapshots every hour) with removal of black frames (snapshots at night). It works BUT, whenever a black frame has been removed (or ignored), the video stucks at that point. I want to have a smooth video with 30 fps as result and don't want to fill up the ignored frames with copies etc.

What i've tried:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i /home/pictures/%*.jpg -c:v libx264 -vf "blackframe=0,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=50:function=less,scale=640:-2,format=yuv420p" -crf 28 /home/out.mp4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Retime the remaining frames.

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i /home/pictures/%*.jpg -vf "blackframe=0,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=50:function=less,setpts=N/FR/TB,scale=640:-2,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -crf 28 /home/out.mp4`

Comment: brilliant, thanks a lot!